# what are the ".resources" and ".cache" files of the "obj" folder? (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, compilation

I just compiled with visual basic .net, I need to know what are the ".resources" and ".cache" files of the "obj" folder used for?

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of posts available online to describe the Obj/Bin folders and the files inside each of them.

Just for a high level explanation-

**Resource files** are typically any non-executable data file used by your application, such as image, audio, and video files. A resource file can also have specific meanings in certain contexts.

**Cache files** are the intermediate source files which Visual Studio caches before build starts. Specifically the contents of all compilable source files (those with a Compile msbuild node). If any of your source files get modified during the build, then these source modifications will not be used during the build.  The modifications will show up in the editor, but not in the assemblies.